# Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f''(x)=0$ if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=T$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'''(x)=0$.

Tags: derivatives

Suppose that $f$ is a real function such that $f(x) \to T$, where $T$ is a finite limit, and that $f''' \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Prove that $f''(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: this question has another part that first derivative is goes to zero.but i prefer to discuss about above question.

Comment: Please share your thoughts on how to approach this problem, and what you have tried. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for guidelines regarding questions.

Comment: I guess that we can do by prove that second derivative is bounded or prove the existence of second derivative.because we can easily see that first derivative goes to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Using Taylor-Lagrange formula:
$$f(x+1)=f(x)+f'(x)+\frac{1}{2}f''(x)+\frac{1}{3!}f'''(c_x)$$ where $c_x\in (x,x+1)$, and 
$$f(x-1)=f(x)-f'(x)+\frac{1}{2}f''(x)-\frac{1}{3!}f'''(c_x')$$ where $c_x'\in (x-1,x)$, we obtain 
$$f(x+1)+f(x-1)=2f(x)+f''(x)+\frac{1}{3!}f'''(c_x)-\frac{1}{3!}f'''(c_x')$$
so 
$$f''(x)=f(x+1)+f(x-1)-2f(x)-\frac{1}{3!}f'''(c_x)+\frac{1}{3!}f'''(c_x')$$
since $x\leq c_x\leq x+1$ and $x-1\leq c_x'\leq x$, then $c_x\to +\infty$ and $c_x'\to +\infty $ (as $x\to +\infty$). It follow that

$$f''(x)=f(x+1)+f(x-1)-2f(x)-\frac{1}{3!}f'''(c_x)+\frac{1}{3!}f'''(c_x')\to T+T-2T+0-0=0$$

Answer (score 0):

You can also show the result (or a generalization) using the Mean Value Theorem as your only tool:

**Lemma 1.** Let $g\colon (a,\infty)$ be a differentiable function such that each interval $(x_1,x_2)$ of length $> L$ contains a point $\xi$ with $|g(\xi)|<c$. Then each interval of length $> 2L+2$ contains a point $\xi$ where $|g'(\xi)|<c$.

*Proof.*
Let $(x_1,x_2)\subset (a,\infty)$ be an interval of length $> 2L$.
By assumption, there are $\xi_1\in(x_1,\frac{x_1+x_2}2-1)$ and $\xi_2\in(\frac{x_1+x_2}2+1,x_2)$ with $|g(\xi_{1,2})|<c$. By the MVT, ther exists $\xi\in(\xi_1,\xi_2)$ with $g'(\xi)=\frac{g(\xi_2)-g(\xi_1)}{\xi_2-\xi_1}$. Because $\xi_2-\xi_1>2$, we conclude $|g'(\xi)|<c$. $_\square$

**Lemma 2.** Let $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a function that is $n(\ge1)$ times differentiable and such that $T:=\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$  and $U:=\lim_{x\to+\infty}f^{(n)}(x)$ exist. Then $U=0$ and, if $n>1$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f^{(n-1)}(x)=0$.

*Proof.*
Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then there exists $a$ such that $|f(x)-T|<\frac\epsilon2$ and $|f^{(n)}(x)-U|<\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}$ for all $x\in(a,\infty)$. We apply lemma 1 to $f-T$ and its derivatives to show by induction that for $1\le k\le n$ each interval of length $>2^{k+1}-2$ in $(a,\infty)$ contains a point $\xi$ where $|f^{(k)}(\xi)|<\frac\epsilon2$. This immediately gives us $U=0$ (of course).

Now assume $n>1$ and let $x\in(a,\infty)$. As just shown, there exists $\xi\in(x,x+2^{n})$ with $|f^{(n-1)}(\xi)|<\frac\epsilon2$. Using the MVT again, there exists $\eta\in(x,\xi)$ with $f^{(n)}(\eta)=\frac{f^{(n-1)}(\xi)-f^{(n-1)}(x))}{\xi-x}$. Then 
$$|f^{(n-1)}(x)|\le |\xi-x|\cdot |f^{(n)}(\eta)|+|f^{(n-1)}(\xi)|< 2^n\cdot \frac\epsilon{2^{n+1}}+\frac\epsilon 2=\epsilon.$$
We have shown that $|f^{(n-1)}(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x>a$, i.e. $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f^{(n-1)}(x)=0$. $_\square$

**Corallary.**  Let $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a function that is $n(\ge1)$ times differentiable and such that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$  and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f^{(n)}(x)$ exist. Then $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f^{(k)}(x)=0$ for $1\le k\le n$.

*Proof.* Use lemma 2 for downward induction. $_\square$